# Создать массив в Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Всем привет. Такой вопрос. Нужно создать глобальный массив элементов типа <MyClass>, чтобы он был доступен во всех функциях программы. Есть ли такая возможность?

объявление класса:

```
value class card
{
public:
    int suit,number; 
};
```

создаю массив:

```
array < card^ >^ mass= gcnew array <card^ >(9);
for (int i=0;i<9;i++)
{
    mass[i]=gcnew card;
    mass[i]->suit=0;
    mass[i]->number=0;
}
```

Куда поместить это объявление, или как?

Comment: Сделайте так:  

    card a[54];

Comment: Илья, Вы должны знать, что вот этим способом нельзя создать массив такого типа в vc++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я CLI не знаю, могу дать общее предложение, исходя из знания других языков. Может, стоит объявить глобальный указатель на нужный массив (если это возможно в CLI)? И быстренько создать массив и инициализировать этот указатель. Можно делать переменные типа extern card* в этом языке?

Comment: Да, такая возможность есть. Спасибо большое, я попробую реализовать этот способ!

Answer (score 2):

Ты уверен, что тебе здесь нужно использовать именно C++CLI? В нём какие-то проблемы с глобальными управляемыми переменными. В обычном C++ создание и инциализацию массива можно написать намного проще:

```
class card
{
public:
    int suit, number;
};
card mass[9]={0};
```

Если нужно создавать именно в динамической памяти, то надо либо сделать обнуляющий конструктор по умолчанию, либо обнулять самому в цикле.

Вообще, глобавльные переменные - это плохо. Их использование является плохим тоном программирования. Использовать лучше только глобальные константы.

**Ответ на первый комментарий:**

> Пока что не совсем представляю, как писать приложения без использования глобальных переменных.

Надо передавать переменные в функции или использовать классы. Например, часто можно логично объединить в класс одну или несколько глобальных переменных и функций, которые с ними работают.

> В том-то и дело, что я довольно неплохо знаю обычный С++, а при переходе на Visual С++ столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Мне кажется, что ты путаешь термины. Visual C++ - это просто среда разработки. `C++\CLI`, который ты используешь - это расширение языка Майкрософт. Его можно не использовать и писать на обычном C++. Можно без проблем смешивать обычный и расширенный C++. Тогда ты можешь сделать этот класс по-старому, а там, где это даёт преимущество, использовать расширенные возможности.
 Вообще-то, `C++\CLI` предназначался только для связи неуправляемого кода с управляемым, который, например, написан на C# или VB .NET. Просто писать на нём программы не рекомендуется.

> Привык писать консольные приложения, а там все просто, именно так, как вы написали.

То есть, ты считаешь, что использование `C++\CLI` с Windows Forms - это единственный способ писать оконные приложения на C++?! Для обычного C++ есть куча библиотек, например, MFC, QT. Наконец, можно писать на чистом Windows API, подключив <windows.h>. Я считаю, что оконные приложения удобнее всего писать на C# с Windows Forms. C# по своим возможностям эквивалентен расширениям `C++\CLI`, но по синтаксису гораздо проще и больше похож на обычный C++.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что я довольно неплохо знаю обычный С++, а при переходе на Visual С++ столкнулся с такой проблемой. Привык писать консольные приложения, а там все просто, именно так, как вы написали.
Пока что не совсем представляю, как писать приложения без использования глобальных переменных. Похоже, придется многое пересматривать в своих привычках.
Спасибо за помощь, но проблему осталась не решенной.

Comment: Ответил на твой комментарий обновлением ответа.

Comment: Извините, не так выразился. Я знаю, что Visual c++- это не отдельный язык, а среда программирования. И так же использую обычный С++ в Visual- среде, это хорошо заметно в коде. Хотелось бы писать приложения в С++/CLI, так как сравнительно давно занимаюсь С++. Но не представляю, как писать приложения с исп-м MFC, QT. Опять же, не хочется переходить на шарп, потому что, как ни крути, а придется изучать его с нуля. Спасибо за объяснения. Но все же, каким средством мне реализовать свою инициативу кодить? Не охота кидаться из крайности в крайность.

Comment: >Но все же, каким средством мне реализовать свою инициативу кодить? Не охота кидаться из крайности в крайность.

 Пользуйся тем, что можно смешивать обычный C++ с расширениями. Эту часть кода выше можно переписать на обычный C++, а работа с окнами GUI пусть будет написана на `C++\CLI`.


>Опять же, не хочется переходить на шарп, потому что, как ни крути, а придется изучать его с нуля.

 Его можно изучить за неделю, если уже знаешь C++ и CLI-расширение.

Comment: Спасибо, буду дальше разбираться! Вот разберусь с плюсами, а там уже и шарп попробую обязятельно).

Answer (score 1):

Скажу как .net программист. Я еще никогда не встречал C++/CLI на реальных проектах, он громоздкий и не удобный.Примерно 70% процентов .net приложений пишется на C#, 25% - VB, <5% - IronPython. Так что подумай, имеет ли вообще смысл в нем разбираться. Мне кажется C# более простой, удобный и перспективный язык

Comment: А вообще, чем дальше от Билла Гейтса, тем лучше.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] p = new int[3] = { 1,2,3 }; //это я создал массив с тремя полями типа инт

for(int i=0; i < 3; i++)
{
   cout << p[i];
}
```

Вызывать можешь вот так:

Comment: Что это за язык такой?

Это

    int[] p = new int[3] = { 1,2,3 };

 больше похоже на C#, но в C# не нужно ставить знак = при инициализации выделенного массива.

    cout << p[i];

 А это явно C++.

>Вызывать можешь вот так:

`Unexpected end of file.`

Comment: Да, запоролся.

    int* array = new int*[row_count];
    
    for(int r = 0; r < row_count; r++)
    array[r] = new int[column_count];

Comment: Извините, вы вопрос вообще смотрите?  Я здесь не увидел ни классов, ни массива, который будет типа "класс" и в то же время к нему будут имет доступ все функции программы, т.е. массив должен быть глобального типа.
А ту информацию, что вы написали, я знаю и так хорошо, ибо работал с С++ больше года.